# Building war and runnable jar with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have started a new Java project using Maven.
I wrote a set of core functionalities, a REST web service which use them, and a command line interface.
When I run maven package, I would like to be able to:

1. Build a war with the web service, AND
2. Build a runnable jar which packs the dependencies and starts the command line interface

How have I to configure Maven in order to reach the goal?

---

Let me add some details.
I already know how to produce only a WAR, and how to produce only a JAR.
What I need is to produce BOTH with ONE `maven package`.
The WAR have to be deployable on a Tomcat, which should display the index.jsp page.
The JAR have to be runnable from the console.

Comment: What I would do is build a project pom.xml and then have 3 sub modules: CLI, web app, and shared code. That keeps things well organized.  As far as I know you cannot create a WAR and a JAR in one project output.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the Runnable JAR (point 2), you should use maven-assembly-plugin, which will create a JAR with all the dependencies you need, and you can run it from the command line. On the plugins section of your pom.xml, you have to add something like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

The you can run:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

More info, can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/).
Hope it helps!

Comment: I have added some details to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For point 1, I would start by using Maven itself to create a pom.xml that can be used to build your web app.

```
$ mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} 
-DartifactId={project-name} 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

See [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_web_application.htm) for more.

Once you've added your code to the source tree appropriately and built the WAR, you can copy it to your application server and it should be ready to go.

Comment: I have added some details to my question.